# Incorrect Absolute File Path

Tags: java

I need a relative path for a csv file I have called `GameDatabase.csv`. It is in the same folder as my `main` method which are both in `zzz` folder.

The file kept turning up not found so I decided to print the absolute path

```
String db = "GameDatabase.csv";
File file = new File(db);
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.print("\npath " + path);
```

The output is

```
path xxx\IdeaProjects\CISC_231\FinalProject\GameDatabase.csv
```

However the path that I am looking for is

```
xxx\IdeaProjects\CISC_231\FinalProject\zzz\GameDatabase.csv
```

Why is the absolute file path printing this out? What is going on in the background and how can I change it to get the correct file path?

Comment: What do you mean by your `main` method being in the `zzz` folder? How and where do you run the Java program? This is important to tell the working directory where files are looked for.

Comment: @LutzHorn I run it with IntelliJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because, when you look for a file, the default directory is the project one (in this case `FinalProject`)

I structured the project as follows

[image]

`Main.java` and `GameDatabase.csv` are both in `src`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new File("GameDatabase.csv").exists()); // the file does not exist in FinalProject folder
        System.out.println(new File("src/GameDatabase.csv").exists()); // but exists in FinalProject/src
        System.out.println(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("GameDatabase.csv").toString()); // this is a solution to look for the file within the classpath
    }
}
```

The output is

```
false
true
java.io.BufferedInputStream@7852e922
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String db = "GameDatabase.csv";
File file = new File(db)
```

You can create a File object representing a file that doesn't actually exist. What you have done is creating a File object representing the file `"GameDatabase.csv"` in the current working directory (this file does not exist) and then you printed the absolute path it would have if it existed.